# How to show multiple labels in vue multiselect dropdown

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have used vue multiselect for my laravel app

In form I have done this

```
<multiselect v-model="selected" track-by="id" label="name" :options="options" :loading="isLoading" :internal-search="false" @search-change="getData" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true":internal-search="false" name="books[]" :show-labels="false" :custom-label="customLabel"></multiselect>
```

and in my vue file I have done this

```
    Vue.component('coupon-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                books: [],
            },
            isLoading: false,
            options: [],
            selected: [],

        }
    },
    methods: {
        customLabel ({ name, sku }) {
          return `${name} — ${sku}`
        },
        getData(query){
            this.isLoading = true;

            axios.post('/admin/books/find/'+query)
            .then((response) => {
                this.options = response.data;
                this.isLoading = false;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        },
    },
    watch: {
        selected (newValues) {
             this.form.books = newValues.map(obj => obj.id)
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see I have used ajax remote options and used custom-label too But it is giving me the error like this

[image]

Anyone can help Why it is showing me this ...

Comment: yes I think so it does

Comment: Please can you show the entire markup for the form.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is you are passing `:internal-search="false"` twice to `multiselect` which gives me an error when I test it. Try removing the second one and see if the same error persists.